# How to Combine Excel Workbooks into One Workbook and Name the Worksheets

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to combine several Excel workbooks into a single workbook while naming the worksheets the file name of the copied workbook.

I've tried moving $Worksheet.Name within the for loop and outside.  It still only gives a name to the empty worksheet in the new workbook - naming it the last file copied.

```
$ExcelObject=New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$ExcelObject.visible=$true
$ExcelFiles=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\u1\Documents\Testing

$Workbook=$ExcelObject.Workbooks.add()
$Worksheet=$Workbook.Sheets.Item("Sheet1")

foreach($ExcelFile in $ExcelFiles){

$Everyexcel=$ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile.FullName)
$Everysheet=$Everyexcel.sheets.item(1)
$Everysheet.Copy($Worksheet)
$Worksheet.Name = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ExcelFile) 
$Everyexcel.Close()
}

$Workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\u1\Documents\Testing\New\merged.xlsx")
$ExcelObject.Quit()
```

The new workbook is created (merged.xlsx) but the worksheets are all named Sheet1(...) except for one empty worksheet that is named the last file in the directory.  I also get the following errors.
Excel cannot access 'New'.  The document may be read-only or encrypted.
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the `$Everysheet.Copy($Worksheet)` call is copying both the values and the sheet names from `$Everysheet` and placing it before `$Worksheet`. You can see the documentation of the Copy method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.copy?view=vsto-2017).

I'm unsure of how you'd track the sheet names to the individual workbooks in order to rename them, however I highly recommend using the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module for any Excel-related files. It makes them much easier to work with and only takes a couple seconds to get it working. Moreover it has the benefit of using reading and editing Excel files **without** needing Microsoft Excel to be installed.

You can accomplish what you're looking to do in a few lines:

```
$exportExcelPath = "C:\Users\u1\Documents\Testing\New\merged.xlsx"

$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\u1\Documents\Testing' -Filter "*.xlsx"
foreach ($excelFile in $excelFiles)
{
    Import-Excel -Path $excelFile.FullName | Export-Excel -Path $exportExcelPath -WorkSheetname ([io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($excelFile))
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly (after I installed the module).  Thanks!!